# Need help writing query for Mongo DB for string does not contain

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'm a total beginner to querying Mongo DB, and need some help! This should be an easy one! I'm trying to write a query to show only opportunities that are not from an event. So, I'm trying to query my database for when my lead source does NOT contain the string "show" or "event". These phrases could be anywhere in the string, for example "Miami Show - 2022" or "Orlando 2021 Event".

So far, my query below is not working because (1) it does not include event and (2) does not account for other text being before or after "show" or "event".

Any ideas?

`{leadsource:{ "$not":/show/i}}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.find({
$and: [
{
  key: {
    $not: {
      "$regex": "event",
      "$options": "i"
      }
    }
  },
 {
  key: {
    $not: {
      "$regex": "show",
      "$options": "i"
      }
    }
  }
]
})
```

Explained:

Match sentences that do not cotain at least one "event" or at least one "show".

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hQYAVlmC5Mj)